# Python: Relative import from an imported file doesn't work

Tags: python-import

Suppose, I have a bunch of Python files in a directory, which all import each other, and can be imported to the app in its parent directory:

./app.py
./my_module/my_file1.py
./my_module/my_file2.py

I then import 'frood' from ./my_module/my_file1.py to app.py as:

```
from my_module.my_file1 import frood
```

If my_file1.py needs to import 'droog' from my_file2.py, it needs to write:

```
from .my_file2 import droog
```

Note that `from my_file2 import droog` will not work, it needs to be relative to the calling file.

Now, suppose I also have a runnable script in ./my_module as:

./my_module/my_main.py

If I run my_main.py, I need to import 'frood' from my_file1 as:

```
from my_file1 import frood
```

But then `from .my_file2 import droog` in my_file1.py fails with: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

This all is with Pythion 3.9.

How do I solve that? Do later versions address that?

Note that if I change all imports in my_module/* to use "absolute" (actually just searchable) imports, then imports from my_main.py would work, but then it would not work when imported as `from my_module.my_file1 import frood`